# How to download json data from multiple url's in r

Tags: r, json, dataframe, jsonlite

I would like to download multiple data files in r from multiple urls, where only the number changes. I succesfully downloaded this code, but i need to download a string of numbers (e.g. 29208, 49510, 54604   62759,62760,7002,38175) which have to replace 29208 in the url. I am a total newbie, and eventhough I have read and seen some examples, I cannot seem to write the right code.

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)

df <- fromJSON('https://api.euroinvestor.dk/instruments/29208/closeprices?fromDate=1970-1-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this , you can just do a loop for , and in everytime you change the url parameters, the loop for loop in all values that you want to use in the url